# How to extract a table from a PDF file using tabulizer when the table has both a cell value and a color code?

Tags: r, pdf, tabulizer

I have a baffling question on how to extract a table from a PDF file using tabulizer.

Here is the table. You will notice that each cell has a value but it is also color coded.
https://anhd.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/20161106_anhd_ed_poster.pdf.

I have been using the R code method outlined in:> https://medium.com/@ketanrd.009/how-to-extract-pdf-tables-in-r-e994c0fe4e28

Can you give me any help on how to extract the cell count and color coded risk level?

Thank you.

Comment: @d-treatman Please include ANY code that you may have tried and its error messages. Without your code no one can tell what your specific issue is or Your thinking.